# Speech recognizer not working: PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC error

Tags: speech-recognition, wav, speech-to-text

I have the following audio [file](https://file.io/6L64RxnGa6MX)

It says the word 'down'

I am trying to turn the audio to text:

```
import speech_recognition 

r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile("example.wav") as source:
    audio = r.record(source)
    
    audio_data = r.listen(source)
try:
    s = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print("Text: "+s)
except Exception as e:
    print("Exception: "+str(e))
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format
```

I tried all the solutions [here](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/issues/325)

I tried to convert the audio file using `wavio` and `scipy.io.wavfile`

Any idea how to get around this?

I am using speech_recognition 3.9.0 and python 3.9

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was getting the same error when trying to enter an audio file
In order for everything to work, import the soundfile library

`import soundfile`

Next, I announced the path to the file with the audio recording of the variable, which I actually processed using the library above

```
AudioFile = ('C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\project\\audio.wav')
data, samplerate = soundfile.read(AudioFile)
soundfile.write(AudioFile, data, samplerate, subtype='PCM_16')
```

I don't get an error at the output, and the output is the correct text